# How do I convert a String to a BigInteger?

Tags: java, string, biginteger

I'm trying to read some really big numbers from standard input and add them together.

However, to add to BigInteger, I need to use `BigInteger.valueOf(long);`:

```
private BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

private void sum(String newNumber) {
    // BigInteger is immutable, reassign the variable:
    sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.parseLong(newNumber)));
}
```

That works fine, but as the `BigInteger.valueOf()` only takes a `long`, I cannot add numbers greater than `long`'s max value (9223372036854775807).

Whenever I try to add 9223372036854775808 or more, I get a NumberFormatException (which is completely expected).

Is there something like `BigInteger.parseBigInteger(String)`?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Using the constructor

> `public BigInteger(String val)`
>
> Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger.

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))

Comment: I tried the same but faced issue coz i missed to import java.math.BigInteger

Comment: ok, from integer: valueOf, from String, constructor, this API miss some coherence?

Answer (score 30):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

> **BigInteger(String val)**
>
> Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger.

It means that you can use a `String` to initialize a `BigInteger` object, as shown in the following snippet:

```
sum = sum.add(new BigInteger(newNumber));
```

Answer (score 10):

BigInteger has a constructor where you can pass string as an argument.

try below,

```
private void sum(String newNumber) {
    // BigInteger is immutable, reassign the variable:
    this.sum = this.sum.add(new BigInteger(newNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `valueOf(long)` and `parse()`, you can directly use the BigInteger constructor that takes a string argument:

```
BigInteger numBig = new BigInteger("8599825996872482982482982252524684268426846846846846849848418418414141841841984219848941984218942894298421984286289228927948728929829");
```

That should give you the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

For a loop where you want to convert an `array` of `strings` to an `array` of `bigIntegers` do this:

```
String[] unsorted = new String[n]; //array of Strings
BigInteger[] series = new BigInteger[n]; //array of BigIntegers

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    series[i] = new BigInteger(unsorted[i]); //convert String to bigInteger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you may want to convert plaintext (not just numbers) to a BigInteger you will run into an exception, if you just try to: new BigInteger("not a Number")

In this case you could do it like this way:

```
public  BigInteger stringToBigInteger(String string){
    byte[] asciiCharacters = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    StringBuilder asciiString = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte asciiCharacter:asciiCharacters){
        asciiString.append(Byte.toString(asciiCharacter));
    }
    BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(asciiString.toString());
    return bigInteger;
}
```