# How to read until end of file (EOF) using BufferedReader in Java?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I have problem with reading the input until `EOF` in `Java`. In here, there are single input and the output consider the input each line.

**Example:**

**input:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**output:**

```
0 
1
0
1
0
```

But, I have coded using Java, the single output will printed when I was entering two numbers. I want single input and print single output each line (terminate `EOF`) using `BufferedReader` in Java.

This is my code:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
StringBuffer pr = new StringBuffer("");

String str = "";
while((str=input.readLine())!=null && str.length()!=0) {
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(input.readLine());
}
```

Comment: can you paste your code for try to help you?

Comment: Probably `br.readLine() != null` !!!

Comment: paste your code?what you tried so for

Comment: @AndriasMeisyal It's still not clear. What type of input you want and what should be the output? If you put 1 2 3 as input, you cannot convert it to an integer because there are spaces between 1 2 3 without modification.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But, Sorry, it's single input each line..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are consuming a line at, which is discarded

```
while((str=input.readLine())!=null && str.length()!=0)
```

and reading a bigint at

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(input.readLine());
```

so try getting the bigint from string which is read as

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(str);

   Constructor used: BigInteger(String val)
```

Aslo change `while((str=input.readLine())!=null && str.length()!=0)` to

```
while((str=input.readLine())!=null)
```

see related [post string to bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717240/string-to-biginteger-java)

```
readLine()
Returns:
    A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached
```

see [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

Comment: Oh, my God. Thanks, It works, I can learn more about the lines which you have told to me. Thanks and thanks again for you, @a question

Comment: What would happen if my file contains `null` as string ??? I am unable to read full file, can this be a reason ?

Comment: @astuter `null` is a java keyword. `"null"` is a string. See the difference ?

Answer (score 7):

With text files, maybe the EOF is -1 when using BufferReader.read(), char by char.
I made a test with BufferReader.readLine()!=null and it worked properly.