# Integer.parseInt(string) is giving me number format exception

Tags: java

Why does this code throw `NumberFormatException`?

```
int a = Integer.parseInt("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
```

How to get the value of `int` for that `String`?

Comment: The `String` (viewed from the perspective as an `int`) exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which is 2^31).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717240/string-to-biginteger-java

Comment: That `String` is a not a valid `int`.

Comment: `int` has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.  Are you trying to parse a binary representation instead?  If you are, you've got 40 bits there, so it still won't fit (int only stores 32).

Comment: There is no "value of int for that String".

Comment: What @SLaks is saying in his usual terse way is that your string doesn't actually have an integer "value", although it could be a textual representation of some number, and could be parsed as such.  Is it a binary number or decimal number you have there?

Answer (score 12):

The value that you're attempting to parse is much bigger than the biggest allowable `int` value ([`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), or `2147483647`), so a `NumberFormatException` is thrown.  It is bigger than the biggest allowable `long` also ([`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE), or `9223372036854775807L`), so you'll need a `BigInteger` to store that value.

```
BigInteger veryBig = new BigInteger("1111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
```

From [`BigInteger` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the number string is pretty large for an `int` . Probably this requires a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) .

Answer (score 1):

There is no integer value for that string.  That's why it's throwing an exception.  The maximum value for an integer is 2147483647, and your value clearly exceeds that.