# Cast String into BigInteger

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to cast a string which is meant to be a BigInteger for key ID's in my mysql database calls for later. My JAVA is not the best, I can't seem to find a solution to turn my string back into a BigInt without getting any errors. Can someone please help?

```
String getWPU(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse    response) {
    BigInteger identifier = null
    def wpu = request.getParameter('slip')
    if (wpu?.size() > 0) {
        LOG.debug('using ID as user identifier: {}', wpu)
        identifier = new BigInteger(wpu);
    }


    identifier
}
```

I'm trying to follow solutions and don't get the expected result's. I'm feeling rather stupid today. Please put me out my misery. Here's my next attempt from reading around:

```
    def wpu = request.getParameter('slip')
    if (wpu?.size() > 0) {
        LOG.debug('using wordpress slip as user identifier: {}', wpu)

    }

    BigInteger identifier = new BigInteger(wpu);
    identifier
```

Which gives the following error when installing the JAVA project with Maven.

> Cannot cast object '124' with class 'java.lang.String' to class
>   'java.math.BigInteger'

EDIT THE SOLUTION WAS THIS, as stated in duplicate answers but applied to my use case:

```
   def wpu = request.getParameter('slip')
    if (wpu?.size() > 0) {
        LOG.debug('using wordpress slip as user identifier: {}', wpu)

    }
    BigInteger identifier = new BigInteger(0);
    identifier.add(new BigInteger(wpu));
    identifier
```

Comment: *cast a string which is meant to be a BigInteger* doesn't make sense. You cannot cast a String to a BigInteger. Do you want to make a BigInteger out of a String representing a number?

Comment: Have you checked the API? [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)) What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks, yes my string is actually a number. I wish to convert back from a string type. I'll check the API too. Thanks.

Comment: It would **really** help if you told us what the errors you are getting are.

Comment: @Akah I'm not too familiar with Groovy, but I believe this is Groovy.

Comment: I've deleted my poor comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) constructor:

> BigInteger(String val)
>
> Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a
>   BigInteger.

Comment: If this is the answer to the question, you may want to close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717240/string-to-biginteger-java instead of answering. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled