# How do I create a Scala BigInt from arbitrary integer of length greater than a Scala Long?

Tags: scala, biginteger

In Scala 2.12.7, how can I create a BigInt from an integer initially longer than a Long? I'm looking for something simple where I write an expression that when evaluated is my original long integer expressed as a BigInt.

For example: (arbitrary 75-digit integer) --> equivalentBigInt

that can be accomplished in the REPL.

Comment: BigInt can take a string representation of your number as input

Answer (score 1):

if your input is `String`, you can use [`BigInt.apply`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/math/BigInt.scala#L79), which actually uses `java.math.BigInteger` constructor.

```
scala> val encodedInt = List.fill(75)("1").mkString("")
encodedInt: String = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

scala> BigInt(encodedInt)
res0: scala.math.BigInt = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

[using java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15717251/432903), which `scala.math.BigInt` depends on.

```
scala> import java.math.BigInteger
import java.math.BigInteger

scala> new BigInteger(encodedInt)
res1: java.math.BigInteger = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```